# How backpressure works for a hot flowable with multiple subscribers

Tags: rx-java2

If we had a hot `Flowable` (for example `PublishProcessor`) with a backpressure strategy. How it works when there are several subscribers and only one of them has problems processing received elements?

The subscribers that can attend the messages at the time are affected by the backpressure strategy that is needed by the slower one?

**EDIT**:
After reading @akarnokd suggested documentation and looking at the diagram I've seen that there isn't any backpressure management for `PublishProcessor`.

But what if I chain a `.onBackPressureXXXX()`. To my understanding, it seems that the strategy will be applied to each subscriber, but just want to be sure be getting a confirmation from an experimented developer.

Comment: See [PublishProcessor](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/processors/PublishProcessor.html).

Comment: Thanks @akarnokd, I previously read the documentation from javadoc source code where couldn't see the marble diagram that clarified me the behavior.
I just edited my question asking for confirmation if my interpretation is good